# How to re generate access_token in Oauth2.0 with refresh_token

Tags: java, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, spring-cloud-netflix

We are using Spring Cloud Netflix Zull as Gateway Application for our backend services. Front end is Angular. But we are testing endpoints in Postman only(Front end is under development). We have one module called `LoginServiceModule` and another is `ZullServerModule`. The `LoginSericeModuke` take username and password from front end and make call to the following oauth/token endpoint by including required headers and body.

```
 http://localhost:XXXX/login
```

and response is

```
{
    "access_token": "XXXXXXXXX",
    "token_type": "bearer",
    "refresh_token": "XXXXXXXXX",
    "expires_in": 3600,
    "scope": "read write",
    "jti": "XXXXXXXXXXX"
}
```

and the `ZullServerModule` contains ZullServerConfiguration, Authorisation Server Configuration and Resource Server Configuration and etc...

The `LoginModule` internally calls oauth/token end point like this.

```
ResponseEntity<String> loginResponse =  restTemplate.exchange("http://localhost:XXXX/oauth/token", HttpMethod.POST, entity, String.class);
```

and the response is ..

```
{
    "access_token": "XXXXXXXXX",
    "token_type": "bearer",
    "refresh_token": "XXXXXXXXX",
    "expires_in": 3600,
    "scope": "read write",
    "jti": "XXXXXXXXXXX"
}
```

we extract the access_token from the response and call following endpoint...

```
http://localhost:XXXX/ProjectName/api/endpointname?access_token={access_token}.
```

But when the access_token expires, and when i access the above backend service url, its saying

```
{
    "error": "invalid_token",
    "error_description": "Access token expired:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX(access_token)"
}
```

I know its expired and tried regenerating access_token with help of refresh_token in terminal like this

curl clientID:clientSecret@localhost:XXXX/oauth/token -d grant_type=refresh_token -drefresh_token={refresh_token}

But i need to include this in our code and don't know where to place it.
After searching on net, i came across about `ZullFilter`. I tried all pre, route and post filters. For each request they are all executed (i.e all long as access_token not expired), but when token expires and if i test endpoint, none of the filters are executed and i am getting error response

```
{
    "error": "invalid_token",
    "error_description": "Access token expired: XXXXXXXXXX"
}
```

I have placed sysouts in run method of every filters. I don't know much about filterOrder also.

```
@Override
public Object run() throws ZuulException {
    System.out.println("pre filter...");
    RequestContext context = 
    RequestContext.getCurrentContext();
    HttpServletResponse response = context.getResponse();
    System.out.println(response.getStatus());
    return null;
}
```

I want to control access_token generation with help of refresh_token. How could i code that whenever the access_token expires and if i access resources after expire,then i get to know that token expired and re generate access_token and call the previous call with new access_token.

Answer (score 2):

Typically it is the client that is responsible for maintaining its own token and refreshing it when it is about to expire. Moving this logic into your Zuul layer seems like a really bad idea. Think about the implementation for a second, how would it work?

Once a client's token has expired, it would be calling your endpoints with a perpetually expired token that Zuul would have to try and refresh with every request. This would add a lot of overhead for each API call. You could possibly introduce some kind of hack where you always pass back a new token in a response header or something... but at this point you'd be violating the [authorization flow of OAuth2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.5).

Comment: Ok thanks for information..but tell me any alternative  to resolve this situation

Comment: Clients should call `/oauth/token` with the refresh token before their access token expires.